# Variance of the sum of N correlated random variables with equal variance

Tags: correlation, variance, random-variable, standard-deviation

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) Wikipedia article,

> In general, the variance of the sum of $n$ variables is the sum of their covariances.

> So if the variables have equal variance ${\sigma}^2$ and the average correlation of distinct variables is $\rho$, then the variance of their mean is,

$$
\text{Var}(\overline{x}) = \frac{{\sigma}^2}{n} + \frac{n-1}{n} \rho {\sigma}^2
$$

So if $n=2$ with $\rho=1$, then $\text{Var}(\overline{x}) = \sigma^2$.

I'm struggling to see how this formula relates to the one below,

$$
{\sigma_{x+y}}^2 = {\sigma_x}^2 + {\sigma_y}^2 + 2 \rho {\sigma_x}{\sigma_x}
$$

In this case if $\sigma_x = \sigma_y$ then $\sigma_{x+y} = 2\sigma_x$.

How can I relate these two formulas in the $n=2$ case where $\sigma_x = \sigma_y$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For an intuitive justification of $\text{Var}(\overline{x}) = \frac{{\sigma}^2}{n} + \frac{n-1}{n} \rho {\sigma}^2$, it is clearly correct when the random variables are equal and  $\rho=1$, and when the random variables are independent  and  $\rho=0$. Given the definition of variance and covariance and correlation, it is plausible that it is a linear function of $\rho$ and so must be that expression

Comment: To actually prove it, it is probably easiest if you let $y_i=x_i-\mu_{x_i}$ and expand and tidy up $\text{Var}(\overline{x}) =\text{Var}(\overline{y}) =\mathbb E[\overline{y}^2] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum\left(\left(\sum y_i\right)^2\right)= \frac{1}{n^2}\left(n\sigma^2 + (n^2-n)\rho\sigma^2\right)$

Comment: Your rounded $\sigma=0.242$ is consistent with the expression and your assumptions

Comment: Re the edit: what you mean by "relate" is unclear, but you could observe that both formulas lead to the same result.  You have to bear in mind that $\bar x$ is the sum of the two variables *divided by* $n$ and that division by $n$ thereby divides the variance by $n^2.$

Comment: Thank you. Let's say I invert the first formula and I have the variance of the mean, then for $\rho=1$, the calculated value of $\sigma$ is the same as the value of $\text{Var}(\overline{x})$, which doesn't sense to me. For example, if $n=50$ and $\text{Var}(\overline{x}) = 4$, then the first formula implies that $\sigma=4$ at $\rho=1$. I don't understand this.

In other words, how can the mean of the variance be the same as the standard deviation of each population member when the population is perfectly correlated?